# Reduce the distance between the max and min of a sine wave?

Tags: trigonometry

I happen to suck at trig but I am writing a program in unity game engine. I was wondering if it is possible, how would you decrease the distance between a sin waves min and max?

Comment: also I need it explained like you're talking to a kindergartner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x) = \sin(x)$

Then $f(ax) = \sin(ax), a > 1 \Rightarrow$ A horizontal 'squeeze' of the graph, scale factor $ a$

Also, $\frac{1}{a}f(x) , a>1$ provides a vertical 'squeeze' scale factor $a$